# innerHTML doesn't work properly in dynamically taken HTML from another element

Tags: innerhtml

There is a table that js creates dynamically.
A button triggers a function that get the tables first rows innerHTML.
And replace its  with 
While raplacing it takes style informations as is to the divs.
After these i add some extra styling to div with replace() too.
But  that function creates and fills with . Is it about percentage width or another thing?

The sample code is spagettied too much. So i couldn't paste here.
I am using HTA (HTML Application) and vbs+javascript.
Thank you in advance
Çağlar

Comment: oops...
http://jsfiddle.net/gF758/

Comment: That jsfiddle is not usable since it doesn't contain the relevant code that actually set the `innerHTML`. Note: successful problem reconstruction is important here.

Comment: Sorry but jsfiddle sample was very complex. Please check the link again :/